# Mypy error on dict of dict: Value of type "object" is not indexable

Tags: python, dictionary, mypy

I have the following dictionary on python:

```py
dictionary = {
    'key1': 1,
    'sub_dict': {'key2': 0},
}
```

When I run mypy on the following line:

```py
print(dictionary['sub_dict']['key2'])
```

it raises the error `Value of type "object" is not indexable`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Static typing is tricky. `mypy` can determine that the values of `dictionary` don't all have the same type, but that's as far as it goes. The *static* type of `dictionary` is `Dict[str,object]`, based on the initial value. However, `mypy` doesn't try to simulate the code further, which means that it has no idea if `d['sub_dict']` is *still* another `dict` at the point where you try to index it with `key2`, which leads to the type error.

One thing you can do is help `mypy` by telling it that a particular value can be treated as having a specific type, using `typing.cast`.

```
print(typing.cast(typing.Dict[str,dict], d['sub_dict'])['key2'])
```

At runtime, `typing.cast` is effectively an identity function; it just returns its second argument. `mypy` treats it like a stronger type hint, saying that regardless of any previous hints or annotations, `d['sub_dict']` should be treated as a `Dict[str,dict]`.

Note, though, that by using `cast`, you are telling `mypy` that *you* are assuming responsibility for assuring that `dictionary['sub_dict']` is, in fact, a `dict` at runtime, since this isn't something that you can convey with a static type. You might think that something like

```
dictionary : Dict[str,Union[int,dict]] = ...
```

would work, but that's just telling `mypy` that it would be a type error to write `dictionary['foo'] = 'bar'`, since `'bar'` is neither an `int` or a `dict`. Even with the more accurate type hint, there's still no way for `mypy` to know what type of value `dictionary` maps any specific key to.

You could use `Any` as well:

```
dictionary: Dict[str,Any] = ...
```

because now you are saying that any type can be used as a value, and that *any* type can be assumed for the result of indexing, and the two types don't have to line up. That is, `dictionary['key1'] = 3` is fine because `int` is compatible with `Any`, but `dictionary['sub_dict']['key2']` is also fine because whatever `dictionary['sub_dict']` produces is *also* compatible with `Any`, and you can assume that that type is itself indexible. In effect, it covers *any* use of `dictionary` anywhere in your code, instead of a specific location where you used `cast` to make assertions about what should be allowed.

---

Major digression: there is a notion of *dependent types*, the simplest example of which is a type like `PositiveInt` which would be identical to `int` except it doesn't permit negative values. `dictionary` would seem to have a similar dependent type, where the type of the values is really a function of the actual data stored in a value. For example, imagine if you could use an *instance* of `dict` with `Dict` to specify the type of its values.

```
dictionary: Dict[str, {"key1": int, "sub_dict": dict}] = {'key1': 1,
          'sub_dict': {'key2': 0}
         }
```

Now, not only could `mypy` tell that `dictionary['key1']` is supposed to be an `int`, but that `dictionary` itself can never have any keys *other* than `key1` and `sub_dict`. (And in this hypothetical world, a `defaultdict` could map an arbitrary unspecified key to a default type.)

Comment: Isn't it dangerous to cast `d['sub_dict']`as `typing.Dict[str,dict]` since my first key `key1` is actually an integer ?

Comment: I was just going to add a note about that. In some sense, `dictionary` simply isn't well-typed; `dictionary['key1']` and `dictionary['sub_dict']` have different types. When you use `cast`, you are telling `mypy` that *you* are taking responsibility to ensure that the cast will remain valid at runtime.

Comment: `dictionary : Dict[str,Any] = ...` also allows to remove the error

Comment: Ah, OK, I wasn't appreciating exactly what `Any` meant. `dictionary['key1'] = 3` is fine because `int` and `Any` are compatible, and `dictionary['sub_dict']['key2']` is fine because `dict` and `Any` are compatible.

Answer (score 6):

A simple change that worked for me is this.

```
from typing import Any, Dict

dictionary: Dict[str, Any] = {
    'key1': 1,
    'sub_dict': {'key2': 0},
}
```

This tells mypy that the values of your dictionaries can be of any type. If your values can be of different variety (integers, floats, strings, dict etc) then you are better off using the `Any` type annotation.

For OP's dictionary specifically, the below might be more appropriate.

```
from typing import Union, Dict

dictionary: Dict[str, Union[int, Dict]] = {
    'key1': 1,
    'sub_dict': {'key2': 0},
}
```

Comment: Did you mean Union instead of Tuple?

Comment: yes @AlanEvangelista thanks for pointing it out. I have edited my answer accordingly