# mypy doesn't recognize Dictionary of Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to check my type annotations using mypy, but this error keeps ocurring:

```
Script.py:201: error: Item "Dict[str, Union[float, int]]" of "Union[Dict[str, Union[float, int]], str, float, int, bool]" has no 
attribute "endswith"
```

My code looks like this:

```
from typing import Counter, Dict, Iterable, List, NoReturn, Optional, Set, Tuple, Union

TYPE_NUMBER         = Union[float, int]
TYPE_CONFIGURATION  = Dict[str, Union[Dict[str, TYPE_NUMBER], str, float, int, bool]]

def check_configuration(config: TYPE_CONFIGURATION) -> Union[bool, NoReturn]:
    database = 'database'
    assert isinstance(config[database], str)
    assert config[database].endswith('.prdb')
```

It runs just fine calling python normally. So I know the result of `config[database1]` is in fact a **string**. Is the problem is my type alias:

`TYPE_CONFIGURATION  = Dict[str, Union[Dict[str, TYPE_NUMBER], str, float, int, bool]]`

or is it a bug ?

The **config** is a dict loaded from a JSON file where the only **optional** parameter is *"start"*. The JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "database" : "bla/bla/bla/file.csv",
    "distance" : 800,
    "t"        : false,
    "output"   : "bla/bla/bla/file-out.csv",

    "start"    : {"1": 1343.786, "2": 1356.523}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54786574/mypy-error-on-dict-of-dict-value-of-type-object-is-not-indexable will likely answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the `"start"` key in `config` will always have a value of type `Dict[str, Union[int, float]]`, then one solution could be to use a [`TypedDict`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/) in your type annotation. A `TypedDict` allows you to specify the expected type of the value associated with each key. In the below example, I've specified `total=False`, to let mypy know that a dictionary can still be considered a `ConfigDict` even if it doesn't contain *all* the fields that were specified in the type definition (you mentioned that `"start"` was an optional parameter).

```
from typing import Dict, Union, TypedDict, NoReturn
    
TYPE_NUMBER = Union[float, int]
    
class ConfigDict(TypedDict, total=False):
    database: str
    distance: int
    t: bool
    start: Dict[str, TYPE_NUMBER]
    
def check_configuration(config: ConfigDict) -> Union[bool, NoReturn]:
    assert isinstance(config['database'], str)
    assert config['database'].endswith('.prdb')
    return True
```

Subclasses of `TypedDict` aren't actually types, they're just dictionaries with some extra info attached to them for the benefit of type-checkers. So you can instantiate them like this:

```
config = ConfigDict(
    database="bla/bla/bla/file.csv",
    distance=800,
    t=False,
    output="bla/bla/bla/file-out.csv",
    start={"1": 1343.786, "2": 1356.523}
)
```

Or like this:

```
config: ConfigDict = {
    "database" : "bla/bla/bla/file.csv",
    "distance" : 800,
    "t"        : False,
    "output"   : "bla/bla/bla/file-out.csv",

    "start"    : {"1": 1343.786, "2": 1356.523}
}
```

— the two syntaxes are identical in the results they produce, and for both of them, `type(config)` will be `dict` rather than `ConfigDict` or `TypedDict` (`isinstance` does *not* work).

I agree with @MarcelWilson in the comments that [Mypy error on dict of dict: Value of type "object" is not indexable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54786574/mypy-error-on-dict-of-dict-value-of-type-object-is-not-indexable) is relevant here as to the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I needed to import from typing_extensions: 

    ```from typing_extensions import TypedDict```

but it worked exactly as you said.